# Disk Size is not Consistent Between fdisk and parted

Tags: linux, lvm, partition, diskmanagement, parted

I have noticed some difference in size displayed using `parted` and `fdisk`. I have a disk attached with a size of **20GB**. Executing the `fdisk` command shows that the size is **20GB** which is correct.

```
fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x22c4d209
```

On the other hand, using `parted` the disk size is **21.5GB**

```
parted /dev/nvme0n1
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/nvme0n1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
```

Why does `parted` show a larger disk size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fsdisk shows 20 GiB, which means 20 gibibyte.
this equals to 20 * 2^30 = 21474836480 bytes

This is rounded by parted to 21.5 gigabyte (GB).

Comment: Yikes. I have missed this.

Comment: Good to know! I always assume that it's GiB everywhere regardless of the actual notation used.